# application crached on uploading file more than 300M

Tags: java, android

I have problem my app crashed when I select 400M file to upload , less than 300M is uploading fine

I changed this

```
int maxBufferSize =  10 * 10241 * 1024;
```

to

```
int maxBufferSize =   10241 * 1024;
```

still same problem

Did i miss somthing?

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String upLoadServerUri = upApi.uploadUrl;
    String fileName = this.file_path;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize =  10 * 10241 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
    int sentBytes = 0;
    long fileSize = sourceFile.length();

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",     "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(     connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[]\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];

        while (true)
        {
            int bytesToRead = Math.min(maxBufferSize, fileInputStream.available());

            // Break if complete
            if(bytesToRead == 0){ break; }

            // Read bytes
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

            // Write bytes
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Update progress dialog
            sentBytes += bytesRead;

            // Publish progress
            double progress = (double)sentBytes / fileSize;
            publishProgress((int)progress);
        }
```

---

```
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ION: alloc_data: handle(0xE4904BC0), len(368640), align(8192), flags(0x2000100), fd_data: handle(0xe4904bc0), fd(0x46)
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Allocate done for all i/p buffers
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Allocate done for all o/p buffers
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): OMX_CommandStateSet complete, m_state = 2
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command: Recieved a Command from Client
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): cmd = 0, Current State 2, Expected State 3
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): OMX_CommandStateSet issued
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Current State 2, Expected State 3
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): Idle-->Executing
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command: Command Processed
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Rxd OMX_COMPONENT_GENERATE_START_DONE
04-04 23:11:24.664: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Rxd i/p EOS, Notify Driver that EOS has been reached
04-04 23:11:24.694: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Output EOS has been reached
04-04 23:11:24.694: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Rxd OMX_COMPONENT_GENERATE_EOS_DONE
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command: Recieved a Command from Client
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): cmd = 0, Current State 3, Expected State 2
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): OMX_CommandStateSet issued
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Current State 3, Expected State 2
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Command Recieved in OMX_StateExecuting
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): Executing --> Idle
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Driver flush i/p Port complete
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Initiate Input Flush
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Reset all the variables before flusing
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Initialize parser
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): OMX flush i/p Port complete PenBuf(0)
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Driver flush o/p Port complete
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Initiate Output Flush
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): OMX flush o/p Port complete PenBuf(0)
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Rxd OMX_COMPONENT_GENERATE_STOP_DONE
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command: Command Processed
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command: Recieved a Command from Client
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): cmd = 0, Current State 2, Expected State 1
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): OMX_CommandStateSet issued
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Current State 2, Expected State 1
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command_proxy(): Idle-->Loaded-Pending
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): send_command: Command Processed
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ION: free: handle(0xEB8C3D00), len(2097152), fd(0x41)
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMXNodeInstance(217): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x43f34670 successful
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ION: free: handle(0xDCAB0D00), len(2097152), fd(0x3f)
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ALL input buffers are freed/released
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMXNodeInstance(217): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x43f34620 successful
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ION: free: handle(0xE4904BC0), len(368640), fd(0x46)
04-04 23:11:24.704: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ION: free: handle(0xD31AE040), len(73728), fd(0x44)
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ALL output buffers are freed/released
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMXNodeInstance(217): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x43f348f8 successful
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): OMX_CommandStateSet complete, m_state = 1
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Playback Ended - PASSED
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): ALL output buffers are freed/released
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217):  Error in ioctl read next msg
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): omx_vdec: Async thread stop
04-04 23:11:24.784: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Close the driver instance
04-04 23:11:24.804: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): omx_vdec::component_deinit() complete
04-04 23:11:24.804: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): In OMX vdec Destructor
04-04 23:11:24.804: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): omx_vdec: message thread stop
04-04 23:11:24.804: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Waiting on OMX Msg Thread exit
04-04 23:11:24.804: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Waiting on OMX Async Thread exit
04-04 23:11:24.804: E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(217): Exit OMX vdec Destructor
```

Comment: Please provide the specific output of your program when it 'crashes'

Comment: You're trying to allocate too large a buffer (`10 * 10241 * 1024 = 104867840 bytes`). Even `10241*1024` is too large (`10486784 bytes`). Also, please [edit] your question to explain what "my app crashes" means - what does your logcat tell you?

Comment: @KenWhite you so ri8 i add  10 * 1024 * 1024; and its worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to allocate too large a buffer (`10 * 10241 * 1024 = 104867840 bytes`). Even `10241 * 1024` is too large (`10486784 bytes`). Try reducing it to `1024 * 1024` (`1048576`) or smaller; it's doubtful you'll be able to transfer it fast enough over your network connection to need a buffer that large anyway.

Comment: when i use 2 * 1024 * 1024 , the 400M the progress bar reset to 0 when its rich the 4% why !

Comment: That would be a totally different question, and you should post it as one. (You can link back to this one in reference, and just post the code that calculates progress percentage in the new one.) The question here is "Why did my application crash?", which is the one I answered. :-) One question per post is the general rule here, and comments are only for asking for clarification of this question or answer, not asking new questions. :-)